# Sort Before Drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to sort my items before I drop it.

this is my code

```
$(function () {
    $('.box').draggable({
        revert: true
    });
    $('.dest').droppable({
        accept: '.left .box',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $newElt = $('<div class="box"></div>');
            $newElt.appendTo(this);
        }
    });
    $(".dest").sortable();
});
```

this is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raika/3bmMe/4/).

this is like what I want to do ([Example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable))

Comment: Which items do you want to sort before you drop? By what criteria?

Comment: how can you sort before drop? Is set to revert if not dropped

Comment: @Raika Sort position according to what criteria? All you have is a blank box.

Comment: but @Raika what you are asking makes no sense and demo doesn't have anything to sort

Comment: perhaps you mean to say you want to insert new element in sorted order, instead of appending it?

Comment: then create a demo that can be used to set up with. First one is worthless

Comment: you need to create demos that are representative of what you need. And provide proper explanations up front of what you expect. The lack of effort you put into your demo is why you never really got any help

Comment: @charlietfl this is what I wanted : http://jsfiddle.net/3bmMe/

Comment: good looks like it's working now

Comment: I thought his question made sense enough to answer. At the very least I replied with very similar question. Which only means that Raika didn't search too hard (or for the correct phrasing).

Comment: using incorrect phrasing :)

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/3bmMe/35/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.box').draggable({
        revert: true
    });
    $('.dest').droppable({
        accept: '.left .box',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $('.dest').sortable('refresh');
            $newElt = $('<div class="box"></div>');
            $newElt.appendTo(this);
        }
    });
    $(".dest").sortable({
        revert:50,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true
    });
});
```

Comment: If this doesn't help, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732011/jquery-ui-droppable-and-sortable-dropping-in-the-correct-sort-location?rq=1) post.

Comment: that link help a lots and work but I want one thing more. that show drop position by some border or something

Comment: That would be the `placeholder` method.

Comment: is there any example?