# Can items in a jQuery nested sortable list be dropped into a droppable section?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-droppable, nested-sortable

I have a sortable list of pages and I want to be able to call a function when one of the pages is dragged into a droppable 'delete' section. Is this possible?

Comment: yes of course it is possible, but what have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732011/jquery-ui-droppable-and-sortable-dropping-in-the-correct-sort-location) SO-Question